# Action bar color changes after load

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

When I first launch my application, the action bar has one color, but as the activity finishes loading it suddenly changes a shade lighter even though I don't do anything programmatically to change it.

This is my styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sp_orange</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleColor</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>

<style name="TitleColor" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

It starts as a nice deep shade of orange (sp_orange as specified) then turns slightly lighter.

I tried commenting out the android:background element just in case I was accidentally setting the lighter color programmatically without realizing it - the result was that the action bar started out black, and then turned to a dark shade of gray.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to prevent it?

Comment: do you know if the original shade matches sp_orange and then it becomes lighter, or if the original shade is actually darker than sp_orange and then changes to match it?

Comment: It seems so, based on launching in the emulator and using OSX's "DigitalColor Meter" tool to read out the screen color in sRGB.